# Where condition with Mongoose Paginate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I am applying Mongoose Paginate on a page that was previously just displaying all records.  My original code in my controller looks like this:

```
let allEvents = await Event.find(queryObject).where('date').gte(todayFormatted).sort({'date': 1, 'startTime': 1}).populate("vendors");
```

Applying the pagination, the new code looks like this:

```
        const events = await Event.paginate(queryObject, {
            page: req.query.page || 1,
            limit: 30,
            populate: 'vendors likes',
            sort: { 'date': 1, 'startTime': 1 }
        });
```

However, I still need to apply the condition 'where date is greater than or equal to todayFormatted'.  But it seems that Paginate does not natively support where conditions; can anyone please advise how I could add a similar condition to filter the records (i.e. not display events with a date in the past)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always write it this way, you will be able to paginate with `page` (default of 1) and `per` (default of 30)

```js
const { per, page } = req.query
const limit = parseInt(per || 30)
const skip = parseInt(per || 30) * ((parseInt(page) || 1) - 1)

queryObject.date = { $gte: todayFormatted }
let events = await Event
  .find(queryObject)
  .limit(limit)
  .skip(skip)
  .sort({ 'date': 1, 'startTime': 1 })
  .populate("vendors");
```

if you are already filtering by `date` in the query, you can add `$and`
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/